# pytest-benchmark integration with Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, continuous-integration, pytest

I know that `pytest` is integratabtle with Jenkins. Is `pytest-benchmark` integratabtle with Jenkins?

Comment: Yes, it is. What's your actual question or error? What have you tried, and how is it failing?

Comment: @DanielleM. I haven't yet tried. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

yes both `pytest` and `pytest-benchmark` are integratable with Jenkins ( source: comment )